# Trouble booting Linux USB

Tags: uefi

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad 320 a few months ago. I’ve tried installing Linux via USB flashdrive( no cd rom included with the machine). I’ve been successfully able to burn the ISo(Mint) to the flash drive but NO usb shows up in any boot option, wether it’s UEFI or Legacy. This is extremely frustrating as I am in dire need of this machine right now. Secure boot is disabled and legacy support is enabled.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Enable UEFI only, the opposite of what you did. Make sure the USB stick was properly done. You may need to set a supervisor password in order to enable booting from external media.

Comment: Wow, seems to be a real problem with [Lenovo](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500207). Please when you DO figure it out post an answer here for everyone else.